# 3D KNN index in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, 3d, spatial-index

I am looking for a way to do fast KNN queries on a dataset of 10+ million 3D points (and growing). I was hoping PostGIS would do the trick with its new <-> and <#> operators, but they don't seem to work in three dimensions. Does anyone know any workarounds that would extend the KNN GiST index to 3D? Right now I'm using a "normal" spatial index with the &&& operator, but that creates all the issues that led to the addition of the KNN index in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know a bit late to reply to this, but PostGIS 2.2 for PostgreSQL 9.5, just recently committed <<->> operator which is a KNN distance for 3D.  For 9.5 it returns true 3d distance, for 9.4 and below, just uses 3D bounding box centroid (so would work fine for points).

Details here:

http://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/geometry_distance_centroid_nd.html

I still need to update the docs, but to utilize the index part, need a 3D index which you create like

```
CREATE INDEX idx_sometable_geom_nd_gist ON sometable USING gist(geom gist_geometry_ops_nd);
```

Comment: BTW PostGIS 2.2.0 is out.  Windows 64-bit builds for 9.3-95 are on stackbuilder.  Other packagers have started building packages for it.

Answer (score 2):

A "[patch that introduces kNN search for cubes with euclidean, taxicab and chebyshev distances](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/9E07E159-E405-41E2-9889-A04F534FC257@gmail.com)" was recently offered on the *pgsql-hackers* list.

Note that the `cube` type, a PostgreSQL extension, can be used to represent points or cubes in n-dimensions (n up to 100 by default, more if that limit is removed), so this patch should among other things enable 3D point search.

I haven't yet used it, and note that one of the replies suggests it may currently break some regression tests. But, it seems to add the necessary <-> operator and "OPERATOR CLASS gist_cube_ops" changes for a gist index on cube distances to work.